# OutputType attribute warning in PowerShell with PSScriptAnalyzer

Tags: powershell, attributes, analyzer

Bellow is a sample function which declares `OutputType`.

I understand this is only for documentation purposes but the problem here is when I invoke PSScriptAnalyzer:

```
invoke-scriptanalyzer . -IncludeRule PSUseOutputTypeCorrectly
```

it will tell me this:

> The cmdlet 'Test-Function' returns an object of type 'System.Object[]'
>   but this type is not declared in the OutputType attribute.

```
function Test-Function
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject[]])]
    param ()

    [PSCustomObject[]] $TestObject = @()

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++)
    {
        $TestObject += [PSCustomObject]@{
            Key1 = "Value1"
            Key2 = "Value2"
        }
    }

    return $TestObject
}
```

The question is that I suspect this informational message is false positive but can't confirm.

I think I declared the `OutputType` attribute just fine, or maybe not?

Why would I need to specify `[OutputType([System.Object[]])]` as output type? if I'm returning `PSCustomObject[]`?

Comment: There is a GitHub issue open for this. You can go up-vote it at https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1471

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified, whatever you `return` from a function is enumerated by the pipeline, so by the time you assign anything to a variable for example, your `[psobject[]]` will have been "unpacked" and stuffed back into a dynamically size `[object[]]`.

Use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate` if you want to return an enumerable collection as-is:

```
function Test-Function
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject[]])]
    param ()

    [PSCustomObject[]] $TestObject = @()

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++)
    {
        $TestObject += [PSCustomObject]@{
            Key1 = "Value1"
            Key2 = "Value2"
        }
    }

    Write-Output $TestObject -NoEnumerate
}
```

Comment: I see, that reminds me of `about_return` just did take a read again, but didn't know it would convert the type from one to another in this case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7

Comment: Indeed; the alternative that is more concise and efficient - but also more obscure - is to wrap the output collection in an aux. single-element array: `, $TestObject` (with or without preceding it with `return`). @metablaster, while it is _in effect_ a conversion, what happens is that the `[pscustomobject]` instances travel _one by one_ through the pipeline, and only on _capturing the overall output_ (e.g., with `$var = ...` or as part of an expression, `(...)`) does PowerShell collect multiple output objects in an `[object[]]` array - whatever their type is.

Comment: There is a GitHub issue open for this. You can go up-vote it at https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1471